# Value Cannot be null calculated model properties MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an model in my MVC application that contains som properties and som calculated properties. When i try to POST a new object of the model to database i get an error that my calculated properties cannot be null.

Here is my model:

```
public class OrderItem
        {

            public int orderItemId { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
            public string orderItemDescr { get; set; }

            public string orderItemText { get; set; }

            public double orderItemFixeedPrice { get; set; }

            public virtual Order orderItemOrder { get; set; }
            public virtual OrderItemType orderItemType { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Time> orderItemTime { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Material> orderItemMaterial { get; set; }

            public OrderItem ()
            { }

            public OrderItem (Order order)
            {
                this.orderItemOrder = order;
            }

            public string orderItemTypeDescr
            {
                get
                {
                    return (this.orderItemType.orderItemTypeNumber.ToString() + " - " + orderItemDescr);
                }
            }

            public double orderItemMaterialSum
            {
                get
                {
                    return orderItemMaterial.Sum(m => m.materialItmPrice * m.materialItem);
                }
            }

            public double orderItemTimeCount
            {
                get
                {
                    return orderItemTime.Sum(t => t.timeItem);
                }
            }

            public double orderItemTimeSum
            {
                get
                {
                    return orderItemTime.Sum(t => t.timePrice * t.timeItem);
                }
            }

            public double orderItemSum
            {
                get
                {
                    return orderItemTimeSum + orderItemMaterialSum;
                }
            }
        }
```

Error shows on properties: orderItemMaterialSum, orderItemTimeCount, orderItemTimeSum
these properties is only calculated as you seen and should not have values.

The problem comes only when i create an objekt and post it to database.

Comment: What's the exact exception + message that you're getting?  If you're using an ORM to persist data, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is that your properties in question are doubles and thus cannot be null. Three ways come to mind to address the problem:

- Convert the properties in question to methods and re-factor your code
  as necesesary.
- Use a view model which only includes the properties you need (recommended)
- Use the bind attribute to specify how binding is to be done when the model is posted ([link](http://ittecture.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/tip-of-the-day-199-asp-net-mvc-defining-model-binding-explicitly/))

Best practice is to use view models. Your view model might look something like the following:

```
 public class OrderItemViewModel
 {
    public int orderItemId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string orderItemDescr { get; set; }

    public string orderItemText { get; set; }

    public double orderItemFixeedPrice { get; set; }

    public virtual Order orderItemOrder { get; set; }

    public virtual OrderItemType orderItemType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Time> orderItemTime { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Material> orderItemMaterial { get; set; }

    public string orderItemTypeDescr
    {
        get
        {
            return this.orderItemType.orderItemTypeNumber.ToString() + " - " + this.orderItemDescr;
        }
    }
 }
```

Does this help?

Comment: I change my properties to Methods and that fix my problem. I tried to use ViewModels but i think i have to read more about ViewModels...